# CPU/Mem/Disk utilization (average) after process has completed

Tags: mysql, memory, central-processing-unit, hard-drive, time

Ubuntu Server 9.10

So there is the `time` command which will show you the time it took for a specific process/command to run after the command has completed.
For example:

```
:~$ time ls
real 0m0.020s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

I'd like to also collect the average CPU usage, Memory, and Disk (i/o) utilization after the process has completed using time (or another command if necessary). 
How can I accomplish this?

Mainly I am using this to benchmark MySQL import performance using different `innodb_buffer_pool_size` settings.

Comment: This is not a very accurate test, the operating system may be caching data to, making you results unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's kind of what the `getrusage` calls are meant for, though most of the fields are unused on Linux (at least that was the case the last time I had to care.

I usually just use `top -p` myself, as it limits top to the process I care about.  You can then toggle additional fields in the usual fashion.  For example, `top -p 1` would only show the `init` process.  You can then watch the performance of MySQL as you do your import.

You can watch CPU stats, memory usage (RSS & Virtual), faults, anything top would normally give you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this'll work exactly the way you want to, but `vmstat <delay>` will print out stats every  seconds.

There's also `sar` which reads system stats automatically taken every 10 minutes, or however long `sard` is configured for.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  In the context of MySQL, you might be better off using tools designed for that purpose.  You have Sysbench, Supersmack, and others.  See the links below.

- [Sysbench](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/)
- [Supersmack](http://vegan.net/tony/supersmack/)
- [MySQL Benchmark Suite](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-benchmarks.html)